# Cannot assign to non-existent property when creating signal and using that

Tags: qt, qml, qt-signals, qqmlcomponent

I want to create an signal so I have an qml file with name TestCreateSignal.qml
with content like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle
{
    color: "red"
    width: 344
    height: 233
    signal sendMessage
    MouseArea
    {
        onClicked:
        {
            sendMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to use this signal in another qml file with name TestUseSignal.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle
{
    TestCreateSignal
    {
        sendMessage: //Error is at this line
        {
            console.log("message sendded");
        }
    }
}
```

but i got error like this when i want to user that

> qrc:/TestUseSignal.qml:5 Cannot assign to non-existent property "sendMessage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#signal-attributes):

> An object can be notified through a signal handler whenever a
>   particular signal is emitted. **A signal handler is declared with the
>   syntax `on<Signal>` where `<Signal>` is the name of the signal, with the
>   first letter capitalized**. The signal handler must be declared within
>   the definition of the object that emits the signal, and the handler
>   should contain the block of JavaScript code to be executed when the
>   signal handler is invoked.

In your case:

```
TestCreateSignal
{
    onSendMessage:
    {
        console.log("message sendded");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed but it gives me : >Cannot assign to non-existent property "onSendMessage"

Comment: How strange, I've tried it and it works. You can share your project through github, drive or similar to see which is the

Comment: the problem was for. i have used name of signal onsendmessage and used that. when i chaned it to sendmessage and used onsendmessage when using it worked